# Use different filters on different columns Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a mean to apply a filter on data already filtered.

I just try this but I'm getting an error about bounds.

```
var i = 5;
var jour = "26/05/2020";
   while(i>0){
      k = 0;
      var filter1 = SpreadSheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateEqualTo(jour).build();
      sheet.getRange("F:F").createFilter();
      sheet..getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(6,filter1);
      for (var kk = 1 ; kk < 3; kk++){
       if (kk = 1) k2 = 2;
       if (kk = 2) k2 = 1;
       if (kk = 3) k2 = 5;
       var filter2 = SpreadSheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumber(k2).build();
       sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2,filter2);
       [...]
      }

}
```

I just saw that's possible in VBA such as this :

```
    k1 = 0
    For kk = 1 To 3
        If kk = 1 Then k2 = 2
        If kk = 2 Then k2 = 1
        If kk = 3 Then k2 = 5
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & k2
        If Cells(1, col + 2).Value = Cells(1, col + 3).Value And _
            Cells(1, col + 3).Value > 0 And Cells(1, col + 4).Value > 400 Then
            If jj = 1 Then
                Cells(jj, col + 4 + 1).Value = "Field1"
                Cells(jj, col + 4 + 2).Value = "Field2"
                Cells(jj, col + 4 + 3).Value = "Field3"
            End If
            If k1 = 0 Then
                k1 = 1
                jj = jj + 1
            End If
            Cells(jj, col + 4 + kk).Value = jour
        End If
```

If someone could help me to find a way to get what I'm looking for, it could be very nice and very useful !
Thanks in advance,

Sincerely,

BigBenne

Comment: Gsheet can only have one filter at a time, the moment you add new filter in other column,  you have to turn off old filter and add new filter, the old filter will be gone as well. If you can show what are you trying to achieve, then I will try help you to solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need to apply new criteria to the filter inside the loop?

```
for (var kk = 1 ; kk < 3; kk++){
    if (kk = 1) k2 = 2;
    if (kk = 2) k2 = 1;
    if (kk = 3) k2 = 5;
    var filter2 = SpreadSheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumber(k2).build();
    sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2,filter2);
    [...]
}
```

Probably you need shift the last lines outside of the loop:

```
for (var kk = 1 ; kk < 3; kk++){
    if (kk = 1) k2 = 2;
    if (kk = 2) k2 = 1;
    if (kk = 3) k2 = 5;
}
var filter2 = SpreadSheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumber(k2).build();
sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2,filter2);
[...]
```

Comment: It's ok, I just put a filter on a larger range and set filter on 2 columns in this range, I don't know why I didn't think about that before, ty for helping man !